# image width and height not working with alt

Tags: html, css

I want to set width and height to an image so even if image is not found it will show a border color?

i'm testing where `src` is empty.

Strangely, it works if I remove `alt="img"`

```
<img scr="" alt="img" class="cover" />

.cover{
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

How to make it work with the alt attribute?

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jx0tm3u/)

I'm using Google chrome.

Comment: use  display: inline-block for .cover

Answer (score 2):

```
<img scr="" alt="img" class="cover" />

.cover{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

try to use inline-block;

Answer (score 1):

```
   .cover{
      width: 100px;
      height: 40px;
      border: 1px solid #eee;
      display:inline-block;
      text-align:center;
      line-height:40px;
    }
```

Try using  `display:inline-block;` `line-height` will make the `alt` text to center with your div